# Autocorrelation with Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I want to compute the autocorrelation of some values with tensorflow.
I can do the calculations with scipy / numpy but I haven't figured out, if it is possible with tensorflow.

What I want is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test_data = tf.random.normal((100,))

plt.plot(signal.correlate(test_data, test_data, mode='full', method='auto'))
plt.plot(np.correlate(test_data, test_data, mode='full'))
```

as expected the output of scipy and numpy are identical.
With Tensorflow I tried

```
plt.plot(tfp.stats.auto_correlation(test_data))
```

which I initially assumed, would do the same but gives a completly different result.
Is there a tensorflow function, that does the same as numpy / scipy?

Comment: The difference may be that the autocorrelation in `tfp.stats.auto_correlation` is centered and normalized by default, which is not the case with `scipy.signal.correlate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```py
td = tf.pad(test_data, [[0, len(test_data)]])[..., tf.newaxis]
plt.plot(tf.nn.conv1d(td[tf.newaxis, :], td[:, tf.newaxis], stride=1, padding='SAME')[0, :, 0])
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer provides the correct results. Unfortunately tensorflow seems to be extremly slow, so I might stick with the numpy implementation! (1.5 ms vs 16 us)

Comment: But I also learned about the [...] indexing, which helps me clean up some different code! So thanks for that as well!